# i need to use a library of some one and do some changes

Tags: flutter, dart, github

i need to use a library of some one and do some changes, so i have did:

first step: fork his library.

second step: git clone library_name 'my fork path on GitHub.

third step: i typed in pubspec:

```
  day_night_time_picker:
   git: 
     url: https://github.com/someone/day_night_time_picker
```

fourth step: i did all of my changes.

the fifth step i need to pull my new changes to GitHub repository what should i do?
if i did any step wrong, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on track!

- in your main project: Make sure your url: points to your cloned repo
- in your cloned library: Push changes to your cloned repo on github
- in your main project: Run flutter pub get to pull the updates into your project

Comment: You may want to look up basic git if you are going to be doing anything more advanced. But in short just do.  
git add .  THEN
git commit -m "any message" THEN
git push